# `git diff -w` (or `--ignore-all-space`) is broken

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

According to the official [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
git diff
    -w, --ignore-all-space
           Ignore whitespace when comparing lines. This ignores differences
           even if one line has whitespace where the other line has none.
```

However, a basic test shows that this is not really true.

### Reproduction steps:

1. Create `somefile.txt` with the following contents:

   - Line 1: Any text you want
   - Line 2: Any non-zero number of spaces
   - Line 3: Any text you want
2. `git add somefile.txt`
3. `cp somefile.txt somefile.orig.txt`
4. Modify `somefile.txt`:

   - Line 1: Make any change you want
   - Line 2: Remove all the spaces (will now be an empty line)
   - Line 3: Do not change this line
5. Create a so-called "whitespace-ignoring" diff with **git diff**: `git diff -w somefile.txt > somefile.gitdiff`
6. Create a truly whitespace-ignoring diff with GNU **diff**: `diff -uw somefile.orig.txt somefile.txt > somefile.diff`
7. Compare `somefile.gitdiff` vs `somefile.diff`. You should see that both `diff` and `git diff` have produced a diff that aims to modify only Line 1 (so far, so good). However...

### Expected result:

Both diffs should be the same (except only for the filenames).
Line 2 should appear as a context-only line, with its whitespace intact, unaltered from the original.

### Actual result:

The diff generated by GNU `diff` is perfect; however, the diff generated by `git diff -w` has a critical flaw: **the whitespace remains removed** in Line 2.

Line 2 does appear as a context line and not as a line to be changed; however, **because it is different** from the original without being specified as such, it 1) is a whitespace change that was not actually ignored (contrary to what `git diff -w` says on the tin), and even worse, 2) it's not a correct/proper diff at all as it does not exactly/cleanly match the original file it was generated against (and thus it cannot be relied upon, something that's kind of a big deal for core tools like diff).

This problem is further complicated by [an additional bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221977/git-apply-ignore-whitespace-is-broken) in `git apply --ignore-whitespace` also failing to do what it's supposed to (and so attempting to apply the given flawed patch **will** fail), as seen in the table below:

### A pretty table to hopefully make this clearer

[image: bugs-with-git-diff-and-apply-not-ignoring-whitespace]

`diff -w` and `patch --ignore-whitespace` work perfectly. Not so with `git`'s equivalents.

**Note:** I have tested and encountered the same results using both `git v. 2.15.1` and `git v. 2.25.1`

### Questions:

Given that `git` is such a well-established incredibly popular tool that's been around for well over a decade, I'm very surprised/skeptical that 1) it could still have not one but two rather conspicuous bugs at a rather fundamental level, and 2) I might possibly be the only/first person to notice/report this, after all this time.

Due to the points above, I thought I would ask the SO community first:

- Have I missed something? Or am I really the first person to bother with raising this issue, in 2021?
- Is there any clever/slick workaround for this?
- Is this a legitimate bug that I should report to the `git` community?

Answer (score 0):

- No; you found a real bug.
- No workaround, other than your own: to use the GNU tools.
- Yes, you should report it to the git developers.

Your table could use better labels.  I would recommend `diff command` on the left and `patch command` on the top.