# `git apply --ignore-whitespace` is broken

Tags: git, patch, git-apply

According to the official [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply):

```
git apply
    --ignore-space-change, --ignore-whitespace
       When applying a patch, ignore changes in whitespace in context lines if necessary.
       Context lines will preserve their whitespace, and they will not undergo whitespace fixing
       regardless of the value of the --whitespace option. New lines will still be fixed, though.
```

However, a basic test shows that this is a damned lie.

### Reproduction steps:

1. Create `somefile.txt` with the following contents:

   - Line 1: Any text you want
   - Line 2: Any non-zero number of spaces
   - Line 3: Any text you want
2. `git add somefile.txt`
3. `cp somefile.txt somefile.orig.txt`
4. Modify `somefile.txt`:

   - Line 1: Make any change you want
   - Line 2: Remove all the spaces (will now be an empty line)
   - Line 3: Do not change this line
5. Create a so-called "whitespace-ignoring" diff with **git diff**: `git diff -w somefile.txt > somefile.gitdiff`
6. Note that due to [an apparent bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221885/git-diff-w-or-ignore-all-space-is-broken) with `git diff -w`, the `.gitdiff` produced will have **no whitespace on Line 2** (the line after the changed line) which appears as a **context line**.
7. Optionally, for comparison: Create a truly whitespace-ignoring diff with GNU **diff**: `diff -uw somefile.orig.txt somefile.txt > somefile.diff`
8. Reset `somefile.txt` to its original version: `git checkout somefile.txt`
9. Attempt to apply the `gitdiff` patch we created in Step 5: `git apply --ignore-whitespace somefile.gitdiff`

### Expected result:

Again, in the exact words of the `git apply` docs:

> When applying a patch, ignore changes in whitespace in context lines if necessary.

Here we have **exactly that:** a patch with a change in whitespace in a context line. So the expectation is that `git apply` will do what it says on the tin and actually ignore this context line's whitespace-only difference and apply the patch successfully and cleanly, without any fuzz or error. However...

### Actual result:

Applying the patch fails: `error: patch failed ... patch does not apply`

It should be noted that **using `patch --ignore-whitespace -p1 < somefile.gitdiff` works just fine**, applying the patch successfully with no fuzz nor error.

### A pretty table to help illustrate

[image: bugs-with-git-diff-and-apply-not-ignoring-whitespace]

`diff -w` and `patch --ignore-whitespace` work perfectly. Not so with `git`'s equivalents.

**Note:** I have tested and encountered the same results using both `git v. 2.15.1` and `git v. 2.25.1`

### Questions:

- Am I missing something? Or am I really the first person to notice/bother with raising this issue, in 2021?
- Is there any clever/slick workaround for this?

Comment: Did you report this to the Git mailing list? https://lore.kernel.org/git/

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the cited documentation, the options `--ignore-whitespace` and `--ignore-space-change` are aliases. The behavior of the option is to ignore changes in whitespace, not to ignore all whitespace.

A change in whitespace is when whitespace characters are added, changed between space and tab characters, or removed. But a removal of all whitespace is more than just a change in whitespace; it is a substantial change.

In the provided example, where all whitespace is removed from a line, it is the same as if all whitespace had been removed between two words. Such a change is not just a "change in whitespace", but is a substantial change of the text. Hence, it is *not* ignored.